# How to read/write local file in lync silverlight application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I tried doing that by various methods but an exception pop-ups. My lync silverlight application works fine in browser or out of browser (with elevated permissions) but when I try to do so in lync's window extension (CWE) it throws an exception saying "File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied". Please help!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "abc.txt");

                StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(path);
                writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Data + "\n\n" + ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving to file via silverlight has always been limited for security reasons, if you want to save without prompting the user I suggest using IsolatedStorage.  See the MSDN documentation for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: thanks! Again help me please.. now I'm in another trouble. I have posted a new question here. please check it out. Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809930/contentsharingmodality-contentadded-event-is-not-getting-triggered-lync-silverl